# При выводе двух словарей к некоторым ключам прибавляется "\u2060". Пытался менять имена переменных, но безрезультатно

Tags: python

```
top_players = {'EliGE' : 20, 'TeSeS' : 19, 'stavn' : 18, 'Perfecto' : 17, 'KSCERATO' :16,
'blameF': 15,'NAF' : 14, 'nafany' : 13, 'huNter' : 12, 'YEKINDAR' : 11, 'device' : 10,
'Jame': 9,'b1t' : 8, "NiKo": 7, "Electronic⁠": 6}

top_players_1 = {'broky' : 20,  'EliGE⁠' : 19,  'ropz' : 18,  'Twistzz' : 17,  'stavn' : 16, 'KSCERATO'  : 15,'NAF' : 14,  'blameF'  : 13, 'huNter' : 12, 'device' : 11,  'Jame' : 10,
'b1t⁠': 9,  'YEKINDAR' : 8,'electroNic' : 7,'HObbit' : 6}

print(top_players)

print()

print(top_players_1)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Значит этот символ и в самом деле присутствует в ваших строках. https://unicode-table.com/ru/2060/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Открыл ваш код в редакторе (visual studio code), он обнаружил 3 скрытых символа в конце слов 'EliGE⁠', 'b1t⁠', "Electronic⁠" просто удалите их. [image: Ваш код в редакторе]

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 0):

Можете удалить эти символы из ключей словаря, вот вам небольшая функция для этого, пересоздающая словарь с помощью *словарного включения*:

```
def clean_dict(d):
    return {k.replace('\u2060',''): v for k, v in d.items()}

top_players = clean_dict(top_players)
top_players_1 = clean_dict(top_players_1)
```